# 2-Step API Login in Flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart, authentication

I have API and in the flutter application my user will fill in username, tax number, password to make a request through api to get details from database like year and database number to show user on the screen and when the user selects year and database number using dropdown, I want to make another request through api with all of the information combined (username, tax number, password, selected year, selected database number) to get login token ....so basically there will be 2 requests before logging in....I want code in flutter and use provider + shared preferences.

Thanks in Advance

I tried many methods but unfortunately none of it worked...I am counting on getting some help here.

Comment: You can hit tow apis in initState method .

Comment: Can elaborate a little bit?... @BijalSutariya

Comment: you want to call 2 apis before login right?

Comment: If yes then you can request api one by one on your action like on button click you have to call one api and on success response call another and after that move to your expected screen till than you can show progress bar.

Comment: Yes, I want to call 2 API's before login and I haven't tried it this way...Seems like a good Idea...Actually I was trying to just make integrated type of API request but it doesn't seem to work ...Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.